Ansible - Getting a key value from every dict in a list of dicts
I have a list of dicts where each dictionary has the same keys, just different values. I can loop through the list and get the "ip" attribute I want but its a large list and wanted to know if there isn't a lookup command that would work much better. Here is a small example of the list:
"current": [
        {
            "fvSubnet": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "configIssues": "",
                    "ctrl": "",
                    "debugMessage": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/tn-MYBD/BD-VLAN_10/subnet-[114.66.71.17/28]",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "ip": "114.66.71.17/28",
                    "ipDPLearning": "enabled",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2023-07-11T08:18:19.497+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/tn-common/monepg-default",
                    "name": "",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "preferred": "yes",
                    "scope": "public",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "19044",
                    "userdom": ":all:",
                    "virtual": "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "fvSubnet": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "configIssues": "",
                    "ctrl": "nd",
                    "debugMessage": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/tn-MYBD/BD-VLAN_20/subnet-[1008:125:0:e56::1/64]",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "ip": "1008:125:0:e56::1/64",
                    "ipDPLearning": "enabled",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2023-07-11T08:18:19.497+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/tn-common/monepg-default",
                    "name": "",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "preferred": "no",
                    "scope": "public",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "19044",
                    "userdom": ":all:",
                    "virtual": "no"
                }
            }
        }
      ]

I am just interested in the "ip" attribute from each dict. Can i do a lookup and get them all or is looping through the list of dicts necessary?

1008:125:0:e56::1 is not in allocated space. Please use real address or reserved like the docs ranges. Reducing confusing bogons is appreciated.

Any data transformation, that does not require a module to be run on the data, can be done more efficiently as a filter expression.
Create a new variable for the expression for convenience (although come up with a better name):
fvSubnet_ip: "{{ current | map(attribute='fvSubnet.attributes.ip') }}"

Jinja built in map filter can get just one attribute for you, so making  a list of dicts into just a list.  Less obviously, dot notation can be used to look into dicts of dicts. More compact syntax than chaining multiple map functions.
Dumping fvSubnet_ip  out indeed results in
[
        "114.66.71.17/28",
        "1008:125:0:e56::1/64"
    ]

If filtering based on other attributes is also desired, consider another built in filter, selectattr. First select which of the objects, then extract the attribute you need.  This is why Jinja filters can be chained together.
As these are IP subnets, note that the ipaddr family of filters exists to do useful things.  ansible-doc -t filter ipaddr

You can use json_query filter, which use JMESPath to extract JSON values.
Note that you have to install jmespath on your host. You can use pip for that:
pip install jmespath

Then we can use the following template:
"{{ current | community.general.json_query('[*].fvSubnet.attributes.ip') }}"


Sample debug playbook with your data:
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    current: [
        {
            "fvSubnet": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "configIssues": "",
                    "ctrl": "",
                    "debugMessage": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/tn-MYBD/BD-VLAN_10/subnet-[114.66.71.17/28]",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "ip": "114.66.71.17/28",
                    "ipDPLearning": "enabled",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2023-07-11T08:18:19.497+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/tn-common/monepg-default",
                    "name": "",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "preferred": "yes",
                    "scope": "public",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "19044",
                    "userdom": ":all:",
                    "virtual": "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "fvSubnet": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "configIssues": "",
                    "ctrl": "nd",
                    "debugMessage": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "dn": "uni/tn-MYBD/BD-VLAN_20/subnet-[1008:125:0:e56::1/64]",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "ip": "1008:125:0:e56::1/64",
                    "ipDPLearning": "enabled",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2023-07-11T08:18:19.497+00:00",
                    "monPolDn": "uni/tn-common/monepg-default",
                    "name": "",
                    "nameAlias": "",
                    "preferred": "no",
                    "scope": "public",
                    "status": "",
                    "uid": "19044",
                    "userdom": ":all:",
                    "virtual": "no"
                }
            }
        }
      ]
  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ current | community.general.json_query('[*].fvSubnet.attributes.ip') }}"

Output:
❯ ansible-playbook demo.yaml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all'

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "114.66.71.17/28",
        "1008:125:0:e56::1/64"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0


I like that answer but our Ansible setup is containerized so I will have to check and see if jmespath is installed on our execution environment.

JFYI, json_query is more robust. Missing attribute ip will be silently ignored. The filter map(attribute ...) will fail if the attribute is missing (You might or might not want it, of course).
